# How to know which from interface a new socket was accepted from?

Tags: c, sockets

I use this code to open a new socket :

```
/* Get all interfaces that corresponds to what we search */
memset(&request, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
request.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;              /* Listening only socket, bind all local addresses */
request.ai_family = AF_INET;                /* May be change to AF_UNSPEC for IPv6 support */
request.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;          /* Only TCP is requested */
request.ai_protocol = SOL_TCP;              /* Only TCP is requested */
/* request.ai_canonname = 0; Official name of the host */
/* request.ai_addr = 0; Address of the network interface */
/* request.ai_next = 0; Only used for returned linked list */

if(getaddrinfo(0, port, &request, &result)) return 0;

for(iter = result; iter; iter = iter->ai_next) {
    int socket_option = 1;

    print_socket(STDOUT_FILENO, iter);

    /* Opening the found socket */
    if((fd = socket(iter->ai_family, iter->ai_socktype, iter->ai_protocol)) < 0) continue;

    /* Make sure to be able to bind the socket while kernel still have it open */
    if(setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &socket_option, sizeof(int))) {
        close(fd);
        continue;
    }

    /* bind this process to the newly created socket */
    if(bind(fd, iter->ai_addr, iter->ai_addrlen)) {
        close(fd);
        continue;
    }

    /* Mark this socket as a listener */
    if(listen(fd, 10)) {
        close(fd);
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

When I call `accept()`, I retrieve some infos, but I need one that I didn't found: the interface on which this new socket was accepted.

Admit I have one ethernet connection and one wifi connection opened at the same time.
192.168.1.72 on ethernet and 10.25.54.78 on wifi.
If someone connect to my server I would get the 192.168.1.72 or 10.25.54.78 value from this new connection, how to do?

Comment: `getsockname()` should return this information (after an `accept()`). You will probably want to store the information in a `struct sockaddr_storage`.

Comment: Stephen, I was searching for this. thanks a lot!!!
I'll try it as soon as I can